# php error : Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, content-management-system

So I am having a problem with my cms coding. It is a database for keeping track of certain people. I need help because an error pops up that says "Notice: Array to string conversion in line 596"

Line 596 of templatev3.php (file)

```
$m_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbrlist WHERE sid = '" . $f_squad . "'");
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What type is $f_squad? Is it an string or an array?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty obvious that the $f_squad value is an array and thats causing the issue. You are using the `.` operator which combines 2 strings, but not a string an array (as loose php is with this type of stuff).

An example of how to fix it would be like this:

```
$foo = array("string1", "bob");

$m_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbrlist WHERE sid = '".$foo[1]."'");
```

As I do not know what your array actually looks like you need to sorta figure that out yourself, but saying [1] after it says that it should combine the second element of the array (the string bob) with the mysql query. If you are wanting to actually put multiple values into this query, you can always loop through them with a for loop or something.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `$f_squad` is an array instead of a string.

Depending on what you need you can convert the Array by using `implode`

```
//string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
[...]" . implode('', $f_squad) . "[...]
```

or simply use the first item

```
[...]" . $f_squad[0] . "[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting should be self-explanatory. You are using the variable $f_squad which contains an array. You should convert that array to string. However as it is an array it might contain more than one value, so it depends on you how you want the code to work.

As you have provided only one line of code I doubt anyone would be able to help you much.

If you only need to query the database using the first value of the array, and the array has numerical keys starting from 0 you could do the following

```
$m_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbrlist WHERE sid = '" . $f_squad[0] . "'");
```

Or you could use any key of the array that you prefer. 
But bear in mind this is not an ideal solution. You could have instances where the array is empty, and this would generate another type of error.